# Inserting values to multiple columns in single row sql server

Tags: java, android, sql-server

I have access to SQL SERVER for android application using JDBC driver. Inserting a value to one column works fine. But I would like to insert values for multiple columns with single query in that single row.

This is what I have tried

```
public void insertValues(String number, Long caller_id) {
    Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
    String queryID = "INSERT INTO Phone(PhoneNumber, CallerID) VALUES ('" + number + "'),('" + caller_id + "')";
    statement.execute(queryID);
}
```

If I try inserting into just one column as follows, it works fine.

```
public void insertValues(String number) {
    Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
    String queryID = "INSERT INTO Phone(PhoneNumber) VALUES ('" + number + "')";
    statement.execute(queryID);
}
```

What am I missing with multiple enteries ?

Comment: I *very* **strongly** suggest you learn about parametrisation. This is ***very*** open to injection. As for how to `INSERT` values for multiple columns, what about the [basic syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#BasicSyntax) documentation didn't you understand, and we can try to elaborate.

Comment: @Larnu I followed the basic INSERT structure. Single entry was working fine. But somehow multiple columns seems not working.

Comment: In the first example you have `Phone(PhoneNumber,ID) VALUES(Phonenumber), (ID)` you define one column in both your rows. Take another look at the documentation. Then plug that ***huge*** security hole you have there.

Comment: Do you handle the ids manually or are they `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`s in the database table? In the latter case, don't try to insert one yourself, the database will handle them... And yes, use `PreparedStatement`s where you securely set variable values.

Comment: @deHaar the ID might be misleading, its the caller_id - which i get autogenerated key from another table.

Comment: @Larnu I am trying to understand your under lying answer. Unfortunately I can't get it

Comment: Ah, ok... Then you are well advised to rename it ;-)

Comment: @Larnu I GOT IT...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all the values in the same set of brackets:

```
INSERT INTO Phone(PhoneNumber, CallerID) VALUES ('0321316768', 'Jeff')
```

You have two sets of brackets in the VALUES part.

(Also, don't just use variables in you SQL statements. Its very insecure! Use `PreparedStatement`

Comment: I have used prepared statement to get the auto generated key from previous table.

Answer (score 1):

Forget JDBC and write your query against the SQL Server directly and you'll see the problem (hint: incorrect syntax).

An example straight from the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-inserting-data-that-is-not-in-the-same-order-as-the-table-columns)

> C. Inserting data that is not in the same order as the table columns
>
> The following example uses a column list to explicitly specify the values that are inserted into each column. The column order in the `Production.UnitMeasure` table in the AdventureWorks2012 database is `UnitMeasureCode`, `Name`, `ModifiedDate`; however, the columns are not listed in that order in column_list.
>
> ```sql
> INSERT INTO Production.UnitMeasure (Name, UnitMeasureCode, ModifiedDate)  
> VALUES (N'Square Yards', N'Y2', GETDATE());
> ```